Clarification on the definition of the Lie Derivative in terms of flow
The question is about the definition of the Lie derivative given in the book "Introduction to Smooth Manifold" by John M. Lee. Thus, I will use the same notation as the book for clarity.
Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $p\in M$. The tangent space at the point $p$ is denoted by $T_pM$. The set of all covariant $k$-tensors on $T_pM$ is represented by $T^k(T^*_pM)$.
Consider a smooth vector field $X$ with its associated flow denoted by $\theta$.
Then, the Lie derivative of any $k$-covariant tensor field $A$ with respect to $X$ is defined a $k$-covariant tensor field $\mathcal{L}_X A$. Its value at point $p$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
   (\mathcal{L}_X A)_p =\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} (\theta^*_t A)_p =\lim_{t\longrightarrow 0} \frac{d(\theta_t)^*_p(A_{\theta_t(p)})-A_p}{t}.
\end{equation} This equation is referenced as equation 12.8 on page 321 of the book.
I can see that $\forall t,  \ \ \ \frac{d(\theta_t)^*_p(A_{\theta_t(p)})-A_p}{t} \in T^k(T^*_pM)$ as it is a real vector space.
However, as far as I understand, it is merely a vector space and does not inherently possess additional structures, such as a topology or a norm in order to define limit or differentiation on it.
Given this, how does the definition of the Lie derivative make sense? Specifically, how can one take the limit in the vector space $T^k(T^*_pM)$ without any additional structure?
Thanks in advance!

All norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent and there is a norm on any finite dimensional vector space (you can define one via a basis and choosing your favorite norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Thanks. So, one can always regard a finite dimensional vector space as a normed space, or further as a topological space, right?
